# How to start plasma-desktop from SSH-console on desktop session?

Tags: linux, ssh, opensuse, kde, tty

I killed KDE's plasma-desktop on a openSUSE 11.2 machine, because it was eating too much CPU. How can I restart it via SSH or another tty session? On the affected computer there is only shown a blinking cursor on the screen, but I cannot type anything.

If I try "kstart plasma-desktop" over SSH the error message of course is "kstart: cannot connect to X server", because I haven't enabled X11-forwarding. But nevertheless "kstart plasma-desktop" is not the completely correct, because I want to start plasma-desktop on a desktop session and not over SSH on my computer.

Comment: On the machine (not ssh) do `alt-F2` then `kstart plasma-desktop`

Answer (score 4):

If you see a blinking cursor that means you're on the wrong vty or the X server isn't running at all. Killing plasma-desktop probably took it down with it.
plasma-desktop obviously needs an X server to connect to, so try restarting your X server. One of these should work:

- `/etc/init.d/kdm restart`
- `/etc/init.d/xdm restart`
- `/etc/init.d/?dm restart`
- `startkde` (If you're not using a login manager)

Comment: "/etc/init.d/xdm restart" worked, but "startkde" gave an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can do it without restarting whole X.
Just export DISPLAY variable before your command to tell where is your X server and display:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or what is your DISPLAY and then run your command. Or even just put variable before command:

```
DISPLAY=:0 kstart plasma-desktop
```

should work.